# How to upload a large file through an Azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, file-upload, streaming, azure-functions

I am exploring Azure Functions. The scenarios I have tested so far work great.

I am at a point where I am trying to figure out a way to upload files (20MB+) through an Azure Function.

The idea is that the Azure Function would first validate whether or not the authenticated user is allowed to upload the file before getting a hold on the request's stream and saving it to the BLOB storage.

Here is the code from the client side which creates a `StreamContent` to beam the bytes to the server:

```
using (Stream fileStream = ...)
{
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    streamContent.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
    streamContent.Headers.Add("FileId", fileId);

    var responseMessage = await m_httpClient.PutAsync(<validURI>, streamContent);

    responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    succeeded = true;
}
```

Here is the code on the server side.

```
[FunctionName("upload-data")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    try
    {
         //  Initialize stuff.

         //  Validate authenticated user & privileges.  

         //  Get the content stream of the request and 
         //  save it in the BLOB storage.

         return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exc);
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint right at the beginning of the method. I was expecting the breakpoint to be hit right after the client side sent the request, no matter how big the file is. However it does not.

I am guessing that the Azure Function is somehow trying to get all the content of the request's body before calling the method. I also think that I am sending a file that may exceed the 4 MB limit of the underlying Web Job but I did not see a way to configure that.

Is it possible to upload a large file to an Azure Function by streaming it?
Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have found another way of doing things. Here is the solution that works for me.

[image: Infrastructure]

When a client needs to upload a file, it calls the Azure Function to be authenticated (using the Identity provided by the Framework) & authorized.

The Azure Function will ask [for a Shared Access Signature (SAS) to access a specific Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118346/how-to-get-a-shared-access-signature-on-a-blob-using-the-latest-azure-sdk-net-a). The SAS will give the client access to the Blob storage with `Write-only` privileges for a limited time (watch out for the clock's skew on Azure).

The client will then use the returned SAS to upload the file directly to the Blob storage. That way, it avoids the long term communication with the client as mentioned by Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan and reduces the overall cost even more as the Azure Function is no more dependent on the connection speed of the client.

Comment: But how would you solve such issue when there is no user interaction 'needed'. For example uploading a file from sharepoint to azure storage.

Comment: @CularBytes Although my question did target a use case with an actual user, this solution does not require any user interaction. Any type of service that can make an HTTP call would work.

Answer (score 11):

You are following a bad practice here, Kzrystof. Azure Functions are not meant for long term communication with the client devices. I am not sure, why someone might be interested in guiding you at all to write a program to manage the Azure Function and force it to do what it is not intended to be doing.

> Large, long-running functions can cause unexpected timeout issues.

Now imagine, you might be having a good Internet connection, but the users may not be. There are several other problems that you must take a note of before anything. And this is an excerpt from official documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices.

If I had to design this application, I would use App Service → Azure Storage → Azure Functions. This would be the workflow of my application's architecture.

In the design approach, my applications would take turns in processing this information, such as App Service could take care of the image uploading, and there I can specify whether the user can upload or not. ASP.NET Core, or any other language or framework can be used to develop that side of the web application, and you do know that this can be easily elevated to support a file upload of up to 20MBs.

Why did I ask you to twist the design? You had a Function to Blob, and I am suggesting a Blob to Function, because,

> Functions should be stateless and idempotent if possible. Associate any required state information with your data. For example, an order being processed would likely have an associated state member. A function could process an order based on that state while the function itself remains stateless.

The functions themselves are to be stateless, which means they must not hold any information about anything and solving this will require you to have another middleware (or *frontware*) to communicate with the Identity servers, which is why I am suggesting to use the App Service here as it can contain the necessary information to authenticate the users, and then Blob and &rarr finally Function, *if needed*.

Then, once it gets out of there, into the Azure Storage, then I can have the WebHooks, or the direct Blob Storage triggers take care of delegation from there and process the image in the Azure Function — if there is a need of the Function anymore. Take a look at how a Blob Storage trigger can be used to start a Function for various purposes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function.

Comment: The appeal of the Azure Function compared to an App Service is the Consumption plan (i.e. pay for what you use).

I understand the issue with having Long-running function. Azure Function have a default limit of 5 minutes. Uploading a 20 MB file over a 1MB/s con. could take 20 seconds to complete which is fine.

Regarding the Stateless issue, I am not sure I am following you. My Azure Function is stateless; this is the framework that provides it with the authenticated user information, similar to what the App Service is doing.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you set the ContentLength header you will no longer be streaming it.  You need to use the PushStreamContent class and write to the stream in chunks.

Whether you will still be able to access that stream on the server side as chunks, I don't know.  It's possible that something in the Azure Functions pipeline will buffer streams before serving it to the function.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, I must sent a request to the server and, if everything is ok, I can use the PushStreamContent that the client will use to upload the data. I will try that!

Comment: Weird. I looked at the PrepareAndStartContentUpload's method of the HttpClientHandler class. 

If the algorithm finds the ContentLength specified in the headers of the request, it seems that it will actual copy the source stream to the request's stream (i.e. without loading everything in memory first). 

However, if it the ContentLength is not specified in the headers, it will copy the source stream in memory before writing it to the request's stream.

Comment: @Kzrystof Oops, forgot to mention, did you set TransferEncoding to chunked?  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.Net46.cs#L866

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution (maybe not best practice) is POSTing the file using chunks. But it requires you to keep track of these chunks and consolidating them afterwards.

For example:

- Front End - Send multiple chunks to endpoint (multiple POSTs)
- Back End - Stores chunks
- Front End - Once sending is complete, confirm with endpoint
- Back End - Merges chunks

[Dropzone JS - Chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769853/dropzone-js-chunking)